# ASP.Net dropdownlist within a detailsview not being set in codebehind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have the following code in my codebehind Page_Load function that sets the default selected value of a dropdownlist in detailsview based on the name of a record returned from a sql data query.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.Page.Title = "Editing record"

        'Perform dropdown list population operations
        Dim myDDL As DropDownList = DetailsView1.FindControl("reqCategoryDropDown")
        If Page.IsPostBack = False Then

            Dim ticket_ID As String = getDataKey(DetailsView1)
            'Fetch Category ID
            Dim sqlText As String = "SELECT TS_REQCATEGORY FROM USR_ITFAC WHERE (TS_ID = " + ticket_ID + ") "
            Dim reqDataReader As SqlDataReader = GetDataReader(sqlText)
            reqDataReader.Read()

            Dim category_ID As String = reqDataReader(0)

            'Fetch Category name and set as selected value in dropdown list
            sqlText = "SELECT TS_NAME FROM TS_SELECTIONS WHERE (TS_ID = " + category_ID + ") "
            reqDataReader = GetDataReader(sqlText)
            reqDataReader.Read()
            category_Name = reqDataReader(0)
            'myDDL.DataBind()
            myDDL.SelectedValue = category_Name
        End If

    End Sub
```

My problem is that when the page loads for the first time, even though I set the selected value for the dropdownlist it will not display and instead simply displays the default first name in my dropdownlist.  I tried Binding my dropdownlist before and after I set the selectedvalue, it is commented out in the sample code above, but that didn't seem to do anything.

UPDATE:
I'm setting the data source in the webform as follows:

Dropdownlist:

```
<asp:DropDownList DataSourceID="ReqCategoryData" DataTextField="ReqCategory" DataValueField="ReqCategory"
                                ID="reqCategoryDropDown" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true">                                                            
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Connects to data source a few lines down:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ReqCategoryData" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TTPRODReportsQuery %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT TS_NAME AS ReqCategory FROM dbo.TS_SELECTIONS WHERE (TS_FLDID = 5299 AND TS_STATUS = 0) ORDER BY TS_NAME">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

UPDATE_2:
Ok, so I implemented he SQLDataSource programmatically in the code-behind under the Page_Init function as follows:

```
Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        DetailsView1.DefaultMode = DetailsViewMode.Edit

        ''Setup DropDownList SqlDataSource
        ddlDataSource.ID = "ReqCategoryData"
        Page.Controls.Add(ddlDataSource)
        ddlDataSource.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TTPRODReportsQuery").ConnectionString
        ddlDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT TS_NAME AS ReqCategory FROM dbo.TS_SELECTIONS WHERE (TS_FLDID = 5299 AND TS_STATUS = 0) ORDER BY TS_NAME"
        Dim args As New DataSourceSelectArguments
        ddlDataSource.Select(args)
        ddlDataSource.DataBind()

    End Sub
```

After which I set attempt to set the selected value of the dropdownlist as above.  The page is still not setting the selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps check these items:

- ensure you're calling `myDDL.DataSource = reqDataReader` or some other form of setting the DataSource of your dropdownlist.
- ensure the dropdownlist has its `DataTextField` and `DataTextField` set properly. This could be in code-behind or in markup.
- The 0'th index of reqDataReader -- are you sure that's the intended ordinal for the `DataValueField`?

Perhaps something like this:

```
With myDDL
    .DataTextField = "CategoryName"
    .DataValueField = "CategoryID" ' or perhaps CategoryName as your value.
    .DataSource = reqDataReader
    .DataBind()
    .SelectedValue = category_Name ' Name or ID; depends on what was set as DataValueField
End With
```

**DataBinding - Code-Behind vs. Markup DataSources**

Consider choosing one style of binding your dropdownlist - in code-behind or with a markup SqlDataSource. Having both generates confusion on which bind wins - the code-behind or the datasource. I think it's the SqlDataSource in this case.

Consider removing the SqlDataSource from out of the markup, and create a method in code-behind whose sole purpose is to create the data binding. This is the only place where the binding should happen. If you ever need to track down a defect or enhance your logic, it's the only one place to visit.

```
Private Sub BindMyDropDown(Optional ByVal selectedValue as String)
    With myDDL
        .DataTextField = "CategoryName"
        .DataValueField = "CategoryID" ' or perhaps CategoryName as your value.
        .DataSource = LoadTicketReqCategory(TicketID)
        .DataBind()
        .SelectedValue = selectedValue ' Name or ID; depends on what was set as  DataValueField
    End With

End Sub
```

From your `Page_Load()`, check for `IsPostBack()` and call this method when you aren't posting back.

Comment: I'm not seeing the datasource listed here and the databind comment is currently commented out (with that single quote there) so this looks to be what is going on.

Comment: I added some details above, I'm actually setting the data source in the web form itself.  And yes p.cambell, I'm sure the 0'th index contains the value I want to set the DataValueField to.  Verified i contained the value when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

myDDL.ClearSelection 
item = myDDL.Items.FindByValue(category_Name) 
item.selected = true

-- 
You could also try setting the SelectedIndex to 2, for example, to check it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are assigning the myDDL variable outside of the postback check.

```
    Dim myDDL As DropDownList = DetailsView1.FindControl("reqCategoryDropDown")
    If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
```

Should be

```
    If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
        Dim myDDL As DropDownList = DetailsView1.FindControl("reqCategoryDropDown")
```